# java process does not show up in jvisualvm

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I am using JRE1.7.0_25.  I ran a Java update forced by a webex session a short while ago.  It seems like after the update, I am no longer able to use jvisualvm to check on a running java process (the process is up - I checked).  Barring changing the JRE back to a previous JRE7 version, is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot/fix the issue?  The applications tab in jvisualvm only shows visualvm and eclipse - not any other java processes.  Thanks.

**Update:**

After restart, I am getting the following error:
**Local Java applications cannot be detected.**

http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html#jpswin

Unfortunately, the solution mentioned there does not seem to apply in my case.  Any suggestions barring re-installing the JRE will be appreciated.

**Update**:

The JRE update as for 1.7.0_45 from 1.7.0_25.  I will update once I have uninstalled JRE 1.7.0_45.

Comment: you generally need the jdk in order to see local java processes.  is it possible you upgraded to a new jre version instead of a jdk version?

Comment: I still have the JDK - its 1.7.0_25 - I just did not mention it in the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to remove the hsperf directory from the temp directory - I was looking in the wrong temp directory location on windows.  JVisualvm is working with JDK 1.7.0_45 now (I upgraded to 1.7.0_45).  Pretty much a wasted hour thanks to this browser Java update.

Comment: It works for me, thanks! (Windows 8.1, jdk1.8.0_45, folder deleted located at C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\)

Comment: @PaulB a quick way to get there - type %temp% either in the run parameter dialogue (win + r), or in the windows explorer file path text field.